# Is there an equivalent to MulDiv for Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

The [MulDiv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383718%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) convenience function in Windows API is equivalent to `(a*b)/c`, but it stores the intermediate result of `a*b` **in a 64-bit variable** before dividing it by `c` to avoid integer overflow where `a*b` is greater than `MAX_INT` but `(a*b)/c` is not.

```
WINBASEAPI
int
WINAPI
MulDiv(
    _In_ int nNumber,
    _In_ int nNumerator,
    _In_ int nDenominator
    );
```

When programming in Linux, is there an equivalent convenience function?

Comment: `MulDiv` dates from 16-bit Windows and was implemented in hand-crafted assembler: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/14/10304701.aspx. It was faster than compilers of the time could generate. These days, just use an inline function. Your compiler will do the right thing.

Comment: Just curious, can the compiler do that for 64-bit integers and a 128-bit intermediate result? I think the result of multiplication was stored in 2 registers anyway.

Comment: But `MulDiv` is not equivalent to `(a*b)/c`!  It rounds the result to the nearest integer, while the latter rounds towards 0.  (It also misbehaves if you pass INT_MIN as a parameter: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120514-00/?p=7633)

Comment: It does not only store intermediate value in a 64-bit, it *also* rounds the end result to the nearest integer (so does not simply truncate the result of division). The accepted answer does not have that property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is no equivalent function for Linux.

I created a simple inline function that works (I haven't tested it with 64-bit compilation though)

```
inline int mul_div(int number, int numerator, int denominator) {
    long long ret = number;
    ret *= numerator;
    ret /= denominator;
    return (int) ret;
}
```

Comment: It should add half of denominator (if end result is positive, or subtract half of denominator otherwise; needs to check the signs of all three to choose) to the intermediate multiplication result to round to nearest integer properly.